# replace value with other value when match

Tags: r

I am trying to use a simple base function to map values if both values matches of two data frames, then the old value has to remain

```
df1 <- data.frame(a1 = c("b2","c2","abc2"),b1 = c("bb2","cc2","d2"))
> df1
    a1  b1
1   b2 bb2
2   c2 cc2
3 abc2  d2

df2 <- data.frame(a1 = c("sale","sale2","sale3"),b1 = c("b2","c2","d2"))
> df2
     a1 b1
1  sale b2
2 sale2 c2
3 sale3 d2


df2$b1 <- df1$b1[df1$b1 %in% df2$b1]
```

Desired result:

```
     a1  b1
1  sale bb2
2 sale2 cc2
3 sale3  d2
```

Comment: do you mean matching values by position?

Comment: i mean matching values if it matches with corresponding old value else the old value of df2's b1 to remain

Comment: sorry, still not clear - how do you know to which old value the new ones belong? Is it by its position (row) in the data frame?

Comment: yes by its position @Tjebo

Comment: Check the updated answer - all credit goes to @WaltS

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that you mean matching values by position, here is one base R solution. May all be easier with packages such as data.table or dplyr, but generally of course nice to first get an idea of using base R.

There are most certainly nicer ways of getting the below result. I am not usually using base R for this type of joins

```r
df1 <- data.frame(a1 = c("b2","c2","abc2"), b1 = c("bb2","cc2","d2"), stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
df2 <- data.frame(sale = c("sale","sale2","sale3"), b1 = c("b2","c2","d2"), stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

df1$sale <- df2$sale

joined <- merge(df2,df1,by = 'sale')
joined$new <- ifelse(joined$b1.x == joined$b1.y, joined$b1.x, joined$b1.y)
joined[,c(1,5)]
#>    sale new
#> 1  sale bb2
#> 2 sale2 cc2
#> 3 sale3  d2
```

Note I have changed the name in the data frames and changed the factors to characters, this making the merge possible.

The key is to create a variable which allows the merge / join (however you want to call it). I am using `sale` - this allows to match by position.

**update**

Thanks @WaltS to pointing towards a much easier option. Because the matching is by position, one can do a direct column assignment:

```r
# date frames from above without factors!! 

df2$new <- ifelse(df2$b1 == df1$a1, df1$b1, df2$b1)

df2
#>    sale b1 new
#> 1  sale b2 bb2
#> 2 sale2 c2 cc2
#> 3 sale3 d2  d2
```

<sup>Created on 2020-02-23 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Comment: After you've removed the factors, you could do just `df2$b1 <- ifelse(df2$b1 == df1$a1, df1$b1, df2$b1)`

Comment: @WaltS very true. that’s the by far most direct solution. .

Comment: @WaltS do you want to make this an answer or shall I edit mine?

Comment: You answered first.  I just simplified things a bit.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if this works for you, but much easier if you use the [dplyr](/questions/tagged/dplyr) package, as mentioned by [tjebo](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7941188/tjebo):

```
new_df <- df2 %>% mutate(b1 = case_when(b1 == df1$a1 ~ b1, b1 != df1$a1 ~ df1$a1))
```

**Output**

```
new_df
     a1   b1
1  sale   b2
2 sale2   c2
3 sale3 abc2
```

`case_when` is the `dplyr` way of making `if-else` construct.

**Note**

> You need to have the columns as anything except `factors`, to make this work. Just append `stringsAsFactors = F`, while forming the dataframe, such as below.

```
df2 <- data.frame(a1 = c("sale","sale2","sale3"),b1 = c("b2","c2","d2"),
                  stringsAsFactors = F)
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a base R solution, using `merge` + `ifelse`, i.e.,

```
dfout <- rev(within(merge(df1,df2,by.x = "a1",by.y = "b1",all.y = TRUE),
                    b1 <- ifelse(is.na(b1),as.character(a1),as.character(b1)))[-1])
```

such that

```
> dfout
   a1.y  b1
1  sale bb2
2 sale2 cc2
3 sale3  d2
```